# Why can't I print the first argument passed to my program?

Tags: c, bash, arguments

I made a simple code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    printf( "Hello, just wanted to say: %s.\n", argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

and made two programs from it - `app1` and `app2`.

Now, I'm experimenting with pipelines:

```
./app1 Bye | ./app2
```

and the output put into `%s` is `(null)` instead of expected "Hello,". Why?

Comment: You are seeing the output from `./app2` The output from `./app1` is not relevant in your example command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how a pipe works. When you use a pipe like you did, the output of `app1` is used as `stdin` for `app2`, but not the command line argument for `app2`.

It's like this:

```
stdin->app1->stdout >----------> stdin->app2->stdout
                        pipe
```